# AngularJS $state.go looses data between controllers and not showing in the template

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am simply getting information from my API, and it responds well.
`console.log(response)` will output,

```
Object {id: 1, username: "testmd", first_name: "Juan", 
           last_name: "Dela Cruz", type: "Pediatrician"…}
```

Controller

```
vm.getDoctor = function(id) {
        $http.get(CONSTANTS.LINK+'/doctors/'+id).success(function(response) {
            vm.thisDoctor = {
                name : response.first_name + ' ' + response.last_name,
                address : response.clinical_address,
            };
            console.log(vm.thisDoctor.address);
            $state.go('tabs.doctor');
        });
    }
```

Now I am accessing **vm.thisDoctor** in my view doctors-this.html

```
<a class="item item-thumbnail-left">
        <img src="cover.jpg">
        <h2>{{ appt.thisDoctor.name }}</h2>
        <p>{{appt.thisDoctor.address}}</p>
    </a>
```

Here's my `app.js`

```
.state('tabs.doctor', {
        url: '/doctor/{doctorId}',
        views: {
          'tab-appts': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/appts/doctors-this.html',
            controller: 'ApptsCtrl as appt' 
          }
        }
    })
```

Is my `code` wrong? I've been working this for hours now.

Comment: Where is `vm.getDoctor`? Logic flow is wrong since you do `$state.go('tabs.doctor');` with no data argument and it will create a new instance of `ApptsCtrl `

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for the insight sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting the response from the server, you are changing the view with `$state.go` thats why you are loosing the data. Instead, you can pass the object to the state and assign it to the controller scope back as below.

**JS1**

```
vm.getDoctor = function(id) {
        $http.get(CONSTANTS.LINK+'/doctors/'+id).success(function(response) {
            vm.thisDoctor = {
                name : response.first_name + ' ' + response.last_name,
                address : response.clinical_address,
            };
            console.log(vm.thisDoctor.address);
            $state.go('tabs.doctor', {
                args: {
                    data: vm.thisDoctor
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

**JS2**

```
.state('tabs.doctor', {
        url: '/doctor/{doctorId}',
        views: {
          'tab-appts': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/appts/doctors-this.html',
            controller: 'ApptsCtrl as appt' 
          }
        },
        params: { args: {} }    // Need to add this
    })
```

**ApptsCtrl** (inject `$stateParams`)

```
vm.thisDoctor = ($stateParams.args || {}).data;
```

Comment: Bruv!! Thank you so much!
You really helped

Comment: @Antonis my reputation is low, so my upvote wont reflect, can you upvote my post?

Comment: Sure.i dont see your reputation

Comment: @Antonis Thank you :-)

Comment: @Antonis
how can i increase my reputation
how can I mark this down as answered?

Comment: @markhamknight To mark this as accepted, you don't need higher reputation. On the left hand, you can see a tick mark which you can click

Comment: @markhamknight On the top left corner to the question, you can find a tick down to the votes arrows when you hover your mouse there which you can click to accept the answer.

Comment: More than 15 rep is needed. If you need a solution now edit a post to get 2 rep

Comment: @markhamknight I upvote your question, so you had the reputation now

Comment: @Aruna is right.This is the fastest solution to get rep. :)